# Discord option lists

Tags: python, windows, discord, interaction, openai-api

So, I've recently started using interactions / application commands in discord.py. I cannot figure out how to make it so when a user uses a command it will show a list of options, for fun lets just think of this, there is a command named "customize" this command will add features to your experience but you just don't want to use type script, isn't that pretty boring? Lets use a option list where it can show us a list of what you can add to your experience, if you don't understand due to my bad explanation, here's an image on how it should look: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1095444190193782898/1095822136750375033/image.png

I tried using chat gpt as sometimes it can solve problems quick but it quite didn't understand what I was trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using typing's Literal in the parameters for your function. An example of this is as follows:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test")
async def my_subcommand(interaction: discord.Interaction, options: typing.Literal['option1', 'option2', 'option3']) -> None:
  await interaction.response.send_message("hello from the subcommand!")
```

Note that you will need to import typing to use this. There are also other methods of achieving the same result which you can see here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=describe#discord.app_commands.choices.